# Put values in the label in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a label below and I want to show the value in the label like below:

```
<% @user_zip.each do |usr_zip| %>
    <table id="searchResult" width="100%" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#CCDBE0">
                Image:
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCDBE0">
                <%= f.label(:zip, "<%= usr_zip.First_Name %>") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

In the above code `usr_zip` have some values, and I want to display it, in the label, but its gave me an error like below:

```
syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

at this line `<%= f.label(:zip, "<%= usr_zip.First_Name %>") %>`

Kindly suggest me where I make mistake, waiting for your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead:

```
<%= f.label(:zip, usr_zip.First_Name) %>
```

`usr_zip.First_Name` is already inside `<%= %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead:

```
<%= f.label :zip, usr_zip.First_Name %>
```